# particular solution of the second-order linear equation

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to find particular solution of the second-order linear equation but I can't find $y_{1}$ and $y_{2}$ according to $y = c_{1}y_{1} + c_{2}y_{2}$
$$x^{2}y^{''}-2xy^{'}+2y=0,   y(1) = 3, y'(1) = 1$$
If $r$ is used, $x^{2}r^{2}-2xr=-2$ then $xr(xr - 2) = -2$, I can't go on from there to find $y_{1}$ and $y_{2}$

Comment: Hint: Your equation is an [Euler equation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerDifferentialEquation.html).

Comment: particular solutions are $x,x^2$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner yest but how? can you explain?

Comment: make the ansatz $y(x)=x^{\alpha}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume $y=x^r$
then 
if $y=x^r$ then

$y'=rx^{r-1}$

and

$y''=r(r-1)x^{r-2}$.

Substitute in 
$$x^{2}y^{''}-2xy^{'}+2y=0$$
to get
$$r(r-1)x^r -2r x^r+2x^r=0$$
divide by $y$ to get
$$r(r-1) -2r +2=(r-1)(r-2)=0$$

therefore 
$$y=ax + b x^2$$
Solve

$y(1) =a+b=3$

$y'(1) = a+2b=1$

to get

$$y=5x -2 x^2$$

Comment: I don't understand how you get $r(r-1)x^r -2r x^r+2x^r=0$

Comment: $(x^r)'=rx^{r-1}$ and $(x^r)''=r(r-1)x^{r-2}$ by basic differentiation rules. Or substitute $u(t)=y(e^t)$ to find a linear ODE with constant coefficients.

Comment: @askque is it better now?

Answer (score 0):

$$y''(x)x^2+2y'(x)x+2y(x)=0\Longleftrightarrow$$

---

Assume a solution to this Euler-Cauchy equation will be proportional to $e^{\lambda}$ for some constant $\lambda$.

Substitute $y=x^{\lambda}$ into the differential equation:

---

$$x^2\frac{\text{d}^2}{\text{d}x^2}\left(x^{\lambda}\right)+2x\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(x^{\lambda}\right)+2x^{\lambda}=0\Longleftrightarrow$$

---

Substitute $\frac{\text{d}^2}{\text{d}x^2}\left(x^{\lambda}\right)=(\lambda-1)\lambda x^{\lambda-2}$ and $\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(x^{\lambda}\right)=\lambda x^{\lambda-1}$:

---

$$\lambda^2x^{\lambda}+\lambda x^{\lambda}+2x^{\lambda}=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$x^{\lambda}\left(\lambda^2+\lambda+2\right)=0\Longleftrightarrow$$

---

Assuming $x\ne0$, the zeros must come from the polynomial:

---

$$\lambda^2+\lambda+2=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\lambda=-\frac{1}{2}\pm\frac{i\sqrt{7}}{2}$$

---

The roots $\lambda=-\frac{1}{2}\pm\frac{i\sqrt{7}}{2}$ give $y_1(x)=\text{C}_1x^{-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i\sqrt{7}}{2}}$, $y_2(x)=\text{C}_2x^{-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{i\sqrt{7}}{2}}$ as solutions,

where $\text{C}_1$ and $\text{C}_2$ are arbitrary constants.

The general solution is the sum of the above solutions:

---

$$y(x)=y_1(x)+y_2(x)=\text{C}_1x^{-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i\sqrt{7}}{2}}+\text{C}_2x^{-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{i\sqrt{7}}{2}}$$

---

Using $x^{\lambda}=e^{\lambda\ln(x)}$, apply Euler's identity $e^{a+bi}=e^a\cos(b)+ie^a\sin(b)$:

---

$$y(x)=\frac{\left(\text{C}_1+\text{C}_2\right)\cos\left(\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{7}\ln(x)\right)}{\sqrt{x}}+\frac{i\left(\text{C}_1-\text{C}_2\right)\sin\left(\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{7}\ln(x)\right)}{\sqrt{x}}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$y(x)=\frac{\text{C}_1\cos\left(\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{7}\ln(x)\right)}{\sqrt{x}}+\frac{\text{C}_2\sin\left(\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{7}\ln(x)\right)}{\sqrt{x}}\Longleftrightarrow$$

---

Now using some algebra to find $\text{C}_1$ and $\text{C}_2$ with $y(1)=3$ and $y'(1)=1$:

---

$$y(x)=\frac{21\cos\left(\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{7}\ln(x)\right)+5\sqrt{7}\sin\left(\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{7}\ln(x)\right)}{7\sqrt{x}}$$

Comment: you solve slightly different equation the question has $-2xy'$ not $+2xy'$

Comment: @MichaelMedvinsky Oh yes I see it, I'm sorry :)